# Python selenium iframe click button

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I have a web page containing many frames, one of them contains a button which I want to click! P.S. : I don't know how to use iframes List and select index of the target one but I have some information of how to create XPath.

the html code:

```
<iframe title="Test reCAPTCHA" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=fr&amp;v=wxAi4AKLXL2kBAvXqI4XLSWS&amp;k=6Ld-Kg8UAAAAAK6U2Ur94LX8-Agew_jk1pQ3meJ1&amp;cb=qrwicghkkby6" name="c-ewoxmbtw42b9" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" style="width: 400px; height: 580px;"></iframe>
```

code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get("https://online.vfsglobal.dz/Global-Appointment/")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
driver.find_element_by_class_name("recaptcha-checkbox-border").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@name="c-ewoxmbtw42b9"]'))  // here the issue  
driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a experience like as you.
I could solve it like these points.

1. It may be not a suitable iframe which is different than your expectation. Please check other iframes.
2. Try to use full xpath.

Additionally, add below sentence and then you can check it will be changed or not.
If title will be returned "Test reCAPTCHA", chaging iframe is done.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html').get_attribute('title'))
```